# Spring + MongoDB + Quartz = OptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

on my Spring app I have a job with following setup:

```
<!-- Spring Quartz Job -->
<bean id="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="com.pixolut.mrb.ob.ss.SsGateway" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="scheduler" />

</bean>
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />

</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="runMeJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem is that when I try to save an object by using the **MongoTemplate save** function I get **OptimisticLockingFailureException**

Is it because Quarts doen't support Mongo?

Comment: Some info here http://zeosaho.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/exception-optimisticlockingfailureexcep.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused from a null property on my model.